# QGIS Format columns so that all fields are under the titles

Tags: qgis, legend

[image: i would like to make the titles to move so that each column is one field. I just cannot figure out how to make the columns move without everything moving]

I would like to make the titles to move so that each column is one field. I just cannot figure out how to make the columns move without everything moving

Answer (score 4):

To have column break on legend you have the number of colum to set. Next to it you have an option to uncheck that permit column break inside a layer. Then layer should be divided in different column and if you set the number of column to be the same as the number of layer it should work as expected.

If Map Elements is not a layer but a group of layer then you have to insert column break. There is this option since few time as you set a feature in your legend to have a column break. [Here is the doc.](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_legend.html#customizing-legend-items)